# Ionic: How to Force a page to be "popped" from the DOM programatically (without pressing the UI back button)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, lifecycle, ionic5

I need help with an issue I am having with our mobile app. Our  app is built using ionic 5.1, and angular v10.19.0.

Our app is designed so that once a user has logged in and been fully authentication, they are able to switch between different company profiles that they belong to.

The problem is that when a user switches profiles; although they are send back to the apps main page, when they click on a specific parent tab, the previous page is displayed.  In other words, they are NOT sent to the main parent page for each tab.

Upon reading the link '[How Ionic Handles the Life of a Page](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle)', my understanding is that the problem I am facing is exactly what the article is describing.

***"Pages are only removed from the DOM when they are "popped", for instance, by pressing the back button in the UI or the browsers back button. Because of this special handling, the ngOnInit and ngOnDestroy methods might not fire when you would usually think they should."***

So my question is how do I force a page to be "popped" from the DOM programatically (without pressing the back button on the UI)

My code implementation is as follows:

- `Using the subscription library as follows (contactsPageSub: Subscription;)`

  ```
  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.logger.info('ContactListPage', 'ionViewWillEnter');
    const contactView = this.firebaseService.getCustomView('TelephoneDirectoryPage');
    this.contactsPageSub = contactView.subscribe((viewContact) => {
      console.log('view ref ionViewWillEnter', [viewContact]);
      this.viewInfo = viewContact;
    }, (error) => {
      this.logger.error(error);
    });
  }

   ionViewWillLeave() {
    this.logger.info('ContactListPage', 'ionViewWillLeave');
    if (this.contactsPageSub !== undefined) {
      this.contactsPageSub.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
  ```

Below is the HTML code for the actual directory (parent tab)

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">

    <ion-tab-button tab="directory">
      <ion-icon name="people"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Directory</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
    
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: Can you post the html code of the tabs? Also, If I understand correctly, I think a better approach for you is to use canLoad/canActivate routing guards.

Comment: Hi Callan. Thanks for your offering of help.  I have updated my original post with the HTML code for the tabs (irrelevant/sensitive content removed)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to pop a page from the DOM is by using `NavController`

```
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';

constructor(private navController: NavController) { }

someFunction () {
    // ...
    this.navController.pop(); // if the page can only be navigated to from the app (not typing the url in the browser's navigation bar)
    this.navController.navigateBack('parent-page'); // if the page can be accessed directly using the url
  }
```

Basically this is exactly what the `ion-back-button` does. I personally prefer the `navigateBack` method as I don't need to worry about the page stack. It will pop every page until it finds `parent-page`. the `pop` method also works, but it will have no effect if the user navigated to the current page by typing it's url on the navigation bar.